# Parsing a JSON and have the value logged in a different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new at learning code - so please be patient. I am attempting to create a Jeopardy style game for my wife (who is a school teacher). However, I am running into a problem. I would like to click on a link ($100, etc.) and have the clue (value) logged into a div on a separate page. Through my research, I have settled on creating a JSON object from an array and then have the JSON parsed for index and value.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="rowOne">
    <li><a href="clueJ.html">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="clueJ.html">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="clueJ.html">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="clueJ.html">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="clueJ.html">$100</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the div where I would like the value logged:

```
<div id="clueContainer" class="center"></div>
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var rowOne = array [

{name:"$100", value:"On the world political map, where were some of the major states and empires located about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?"},
{name:"$200", value:"What were the artistic, literary, and intellectual ideas of the Renaissance?"},
{name:"$300", value:"Where were the five world religions located around 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?"},
{name:"$400", value:"What were the regional trading patterns about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?"},
{name:"$500", value:"Why were the regional trading patterns important?",}

];

var json = JSON.parse(rowOne);

$("li a href").click(function(){
$.each(json, function(index, value){
    $("#clueContainer").append(function(){
    $(value).log(<p>+value+</p>);

});
});
});
});
```

Are there any ideas out there or an I approaching this project the wrong way?

Comment: `href` is not an HTML tag. Remove that. Next you'll probably run into trouble with loading "clueJ.html" when the links are clicked. Best is you replace those with "#". Also I don't understand where `$(value).log` comes from... are you using a plugin? Finally, `<p>+value</p>` requires the Tags to be in quotes like this: `'<p>'+value+'</p>'`.

Comment: I am not using a plugin. Can I just use $("#clueContainer") .append('<p>'+value+'</p>')?

Comment: You can indeed. You can even omit the tags. jQuery will automatically generate a Text Node for you. Alternatively you can use `$('#clueContainer').text(value)`. (Aww, too late. Somebody posted that as part of his answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea for arrays but the syntax is a little different than what you have. I've created an array of array of objects. The structure is similar to this:

```
   var arr = [[
       {
          property: value 
       }, {
          property: value 
       }][{
          property: value 
       }, {
          property: value 
       }]
    ];
```

I added a `class` called `rows` to the `ul` element and you can then iterate over that with `each()` using jQuery's built in index (`p` in our case) and then iterate over the number of `a` elements in the ul to add a question from the `rows` array.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rows = [
        [{
            name: "$100",
            value: "On the world political map, where were some of the major states and empires located about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?"
        }, {
            name: "$200",
            value: "What were the artistic, literary, and intellectual ideas of the Renaissance?"
        }, {
            name: "$300",
            value: "Where were the five world religions located around 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?"
        }, {
            name: "$400",
            value: "What were the regional trading patterns about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?"
        }, {
            name: "$500",
            value: "Why were the regional trading patterns important?"
        }],
        [{
            name: "$100",
            value: "Who cares about the price of tea in China?"
        }, {
            name: "$200",
            value: "Why did the chicken cross the road?"
        }, {
            name: "$300",
            value: "How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?"
        }, {
            name: "$400",
            value: "How many SEO specialists does it take to change a light, bulb, lightbulb, energy, electricity?"
        }, {
            name: "$500",
            value: "Where in the world is Carmen San Diego?"
        }]
    ];
    $(".rows").each(function (p) {
        $("#row" + p).find("a").each(function (i) {
            $(this).text(rows[p][i].name);
            $(this).click(function () {
                var value = rows[p][i].value;;
                $("#clueContainer").html(value);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/egHyN/4/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be even better to have "objects of arrays"? Since every row has the same "name", we could use that name as the property of the object and assign an array with the questions as items. Would make setting up the questions a little simpler.

Comment: No...I am coming from a Javascript/jquery background. I actually had my array looking like yours before hand.

Comment: @Derija93, I think I changed something when I shouldn't have. Now they have different names.

Comment: @justLearning, oh ok. Just wondering. Your array looked very similar to the PHP array syntax.

Comment: Still coming up with a blank screen and no questions from my array.

Comment: Works fine in jsFiddle, but when I click on the link in my HTML nothing happens. Does it have something to do with this code: <div id="clueContainer" class="center"></div> is on another page? Christopher - thanks for being so patient with me.

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do that? The alert came up as "paused in debugger."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jeopardy, but the list should contain the values from $100 to $500?
I modified your code, assuming the list is ascending: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVYpL/)

No fiddle without code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var rowOne = {
        "$100": "On the world political map, where were some of the major states and empires located about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?",
        "$200": "What were the artistic, literary, and intellectual ideas of the Renaissance?",
        "$300": "Where were the five world religions located around 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?",
        "$400": "What were the regional trading patterns about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?",
        "$500": "Why were the regional trading patterns important?"
    };

    $("li").on('click', 'a', function () {
        var foo = $(this).text();
        $('#clueContainer').text( rowOne[foo] );
    });
});
```

Comment: Jeopardy has multiple rows and columns. The value increases in ascending order in the columns, not the rows. But still... ;)